# Using redux toolkit in NextJS without next-redux-wrapper

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js

I'm new to NextJS and I'm trying to figure out on how to implement RTK, I stumbled on this [github repo example](https://github.com/jherr/nextjs-state-management/blob/main/with-redux/src/store.ts) from [Jack Harrington](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gRxCvDjWjs&t=1433s) and basically his slices has a rehydrate reducer:

```
reducers: {
    rehydrate(state, action: PayloadAction<PokemonState>) {
      state.error = action.payload.error;
      state.pending = action.payload.pending;
      state.pokemon = action.payload.pokemon;
      state.filteredPokemon = action.payload.filteredPokemon;
      state.search = action.payload.search;
    },
}
```

Then on his page he does this on `getServerSideProps`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  await store.dispatch(getPokemon()); //dispatching an AsyncThunk
  return {
    props: {
      initialState: store.getState(),
    },
  };
}
```

Inside the page component he uses useEffect to hydrate:

```
function Home({ initialState }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(rehydrate(initialState.pokemon));
  }, [dispatch, initialState]);

  return <>...</>
}
```

Is it ok to use `useEffect` or hooks in general to hydrate your redux states in NextJS? also to use `useState`, `useEffect`, `useMemo`, `useCallback` doesn't it make your page client side?

Using `getStaticProps` and `getServerSideProps` when you have a `useEffect` is pointless when you are trying to do SSG and SSR?

Basically what I want to accomplish to be able to do ssg and ssr while being able to use all of RTK features such as thunks, slices, queries and etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would do that manual rehydration, the redux-next-wrapper alrady fires a rehydration action for you. Just put that in extraReducers.